# Локализация приложения для стран СНГ

Tags: java, android, android-studio, locale

Есть два набора строковых ресурсов: дефолтный (англ) и русский. Необходимо, установить русский язык, если пользователь выберет белорусский, украинский, и.т.д.
Сначала узнаю какой язык у пользователя сейчас:

```
String userLocale = Locale.getDefault().getLanguage();
```

После чего сравниваю с нужными языками:

```
if(userLocale.equals("uk")||userLocale.equals("be")||userLocale.equals("kz")) и т.д.
```

Внутри if'a код, найденный здесь же:

```
Locale locale = new Locale("ru");
            Locale.setDefault(locale);
            Configuration config = new Configuration();
            config.locale = locale;
            getBaseContext().getResources().
                    updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

Но при запуске приложения язык не меняется на русский, а остается дефолтным. Что делаю не так?

Comment: upd:Выберет в настройках системы

Comment: Лучше всего реализовать выбор языка независимо от системы

Comment: Может и так, но основная проблема в том, что не работает код внутри if'a. Т.е. если оставить только его - ничего не меняется.

Answer (score 3):

Вам надо создать в ресурсах папки для нужных языков и поместить туда нужный перевод. Именно из этих папок будут браться строки. Т.е. создайте папки `values-ua`, `values-be`, `values-kz` и поместите туда `strings.xml` с русским переводом - всё заработает из коробки, ничего программно делать не надо будет.

Comment: А как тогда делать изменения / дополнения? Сначала делать их в русской версии, а потом копировать в остальные?

Comment: @Pacs31, да, именно так. Один файл изменяете, а потом им заменяете файлы в других папках